# Modify property serialization/deserialization in WinForms Form1.resx file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serialization, design-time

I have a custom class and made the same serialization as System.Drawing.Image, by implementing ISerializable interface and two methods:

- void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) to give the serializer my data in the format I need.
- A constructor in my class: protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)

```
    [Serializable]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassTypeConverter))]
    [Editor(typeof(MyClassEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject, ISerializable, ICloneable, IDisposable
```

A have added my class as a property to a custom button -> MyButton.MyClass
The problem is that at design time when I set MyClass the serializer writes the assembly name and **version** in the RESX file of the form before my custom serialized object. Here is how it looks like:

```
    <assembly alias="MyAssembly" name="MyAssembly, Version=2020.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" />
      <data name="myButton1.MyClass" type="MyAssembly.MyClass, MyAssembly">
    <value>Some long text data</data>
      </data>
```

After a new release my clients started having this exception:

```
    System.InvalidCastException: '[A]MyAssembly.MyClass cannot be cast to [B]MyAssembly.MyClass. Type A originates from 'MyAssembly, Version=2020.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\...
```

Here is the designer file:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form2));
        this.myButton1 = new MyAssembly.MyButton();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // myButton1
        // 
        this.myButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
        this.myButton1.Name = "myButton1";
        this.myButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
        this.myButton1.MyClass = ((MyAssembly.MyClass)(resources.GetObject("myButton1.MyClass")));
        this.myButton1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.myButton1.Text = "myButton1";
```

The assembly where type MyClass is located is already loaded, because MyButton is located in the same assembly. So I do not need the RESX file to contain information about the assembly.
Currently I cannot find a solution on my own and I am thinking of two options:

1. How can I prevent serializing the <assembly alias="MyAssembly"...> in the resx file of the form?
2. Can I load MyClass from the resx file without loading the described assembly?

Comment: Not sure why you're inheriting `MarshalByRefObject` or what is the actual implementation. I suggest to move that class outside the Button class and decorate the `MyClass` type Property with `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`. Possibly,also show the `protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) { }` content, the related `public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` and the `Clone()` implementation (this is not relevant, just for completeness)

Comment: Hi, Jimi,
The main idea was to copy the exact behavior and serialization of the System.Drawing.Image class, but unfortunately I did not realize that the serialization will be a problem(after a few releases the clients started to complain about this exception). As the Image class is in an assembly that has a limited amount of versions - one for .NET2.0 and another one for .NET4.0. 
MyClass a separate class(not contained in Button) and is in an assembly that is released several times a year.
Regards, 
Todor

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but it seems that the serialization in the resource file of the Form cannot be controlled, so my colleagues and I decided to change the way MyClass property is serialized, despite the fact that this will be a breaking change. When used as a property in another class/control it will use a new string MyClassXml property that is serialized as XML, and our MyClass property will not be serialized.